# How can I use Laravel's RateLimiter to not exceed 5000 calls in 10 minutes

Tags: php, laravel, command

The API I'm working with limits us to 5000 calls every 10 minutes.   It's set up to run within a console Command.

Is there a way to make Laravel's RateLimiter accomplish this?

Code so far:

```
$five_thousand_one_hundred_records = User::limit(5100)->get();
        
        foreach($five_thousand_one_hundred_records as $record){

            /*
             * RateLimiter::attempt(string $key, int $maxAttempts, Closure $callback, int $decaySeconds = 60)
             * The $decaySeconds, is how long the program needs to wait before it is ok to execute again
            */
            $executed = RateLimiter::attempt(
                'call_to_john_api',
                $perMinute = 5000,
                function() use ($record) {                   
                    
                    // Ok to call the API
                    $this->APICall($record);
                },
                60
            );

            if (! $executed) {

                // How long until we can call the API again?
                $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn('call_to_john_api');

                /*
                 * You may try again in 60 seconds
                 * I need this to do the above command after sleeping, to ensure that API call happens
                 * sleeping for x seconds.  Too many API Calls
                 */

                sleep($seconds);

                // after sleeping, ok to call APICall()
                $this->APICall($record);
            }
        }
```

The code runs but allows 5000 calls every minute.  I need it to not exceed 5000 calls in 10 minutes.  When it's near that threshold, it needs to wait 60 seconds or so, in order to not get yelled at by the API.

Comment: Emmm, 60 * 10? Or i did not not understand the question

Answer (score -2):

use this code and let me have your respect if it works good ;)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

// Define a route or a controller method where you want to apply rate limiting.
Route::get('/api-calls', 'ApiController@apiCalls')->middleware(['throttle:5,1']);

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function apiCalls()
    {
        // Get the records you want to process (e.g., User records)
        $records = User::limit(5100)->get();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            // Use a unique key for each record to rate limit their API calls
            $key = 'api_rate_limit_' . $record->id;

            // Check if we are near the rate limit threshold
            if (RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($key, 5000, 600)) {
                // We are near the threshold, wait for 60 seconds
                sleep(60);
            }

            // Attempt to execute the API call
            if (RateLimiter::attempt($key, 5000, function () use ($record) {
                // Your API call logic here
                $response = $this->APICall($record);

                // Handle the API response here
                if ($response->successful()) {
                    // API call was successful
                    // Process the response data if needed
                } else {
                    // API call failed
                    // Log the error or handle it as required
                }
            })) {
                // API call was executed successfully
            }
        }
    }

    private function APICall($record)
    {
        // Make the API call using Laravel HTTP client
        try {
            $response = Http::get('https://api.example.com/resource', [
                'param1' => $record->param1,
                'param2' => $record->param2,
                // Add any required parameters here
            ]);

            return $response;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle API call error
            // Log the error or handle it as required
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).